# How to move one element to the left of a fixed array

Tags: c

```
int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

from my understanding, the rest of the indexes that haven't been assign a value will be 0. If I want to move every element to the left (I am wanting to remove the first value i.e. index 0). How do I do this without causing duplicate values for the last index with a integer assigned?

For example:

current array

```
output: 1234500000
```

+1 to the left:

```
output: 2345500000
```

I tried the following code:

```
void order_array(int size, int array[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0)
        {
            array[i-1] = 0;
        }
        array[i] = array[i+1];
    }
}
```

expected output after method execution:

```
output: 2345000000
```

Also before someone says this is a duplicate, I have looked around and no thread explains with fixed arrays, i.e. with 0's as default values.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: don't you want `1` to be place at the old position of `5` after rotation?

Comment: No, Basically the program uses the first index for another variable, and the array needs to move to the left +1 like a queue.

Comment: What result do you want if you call `order_array(5, array)` for `int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (array[i] == 0)
    {
        array[i-1] = 0;
    }
```

I don't understand why this block is there. It's not possible to get inside the if statement.

With your expected output and given this is an array of `int`s, I suspect the solution is to only output four values in your print statement, but if the last element of the array should be zero, you can just do this after your `for` loop:

```
array[size-1] = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that code because the 5 didn't get replaced by the next 0, it would just be double 5's.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

void order_array(int size, int* array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        if (!array[i]) {
            continue;
        }

        if (i + 1 < size)
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf("intput: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    order_array(ARRAY_SIZE, array);

    printf("output: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe you should consider the last value that not equal to default value 0.

Execute in shell:

gcc -o a.out a.c && ./a.out

```
intput: 1234500000
output: 2345000000
```

Comment: This is what i dont want. i want 2345000000, so without the double 5

Comment: I have modified the answer, if you want 2345000000, do nothing when you find default 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want rotation then:

```
int arr[];  //initialize it
int siz=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
int index=0; 

while(index<siz-1)
{
    arr[index]=arr[index+1];
    index++;
}

arr[index]=0;  //0 default value at the end of the array
```

This will work fine

Answer (score 0):

You just need to manually set the last value to zero at the end.  I'd also consider using the built-in `memmove` function which is designed for moving around data where the source and destination overlap.

```
void order_array(int size, int array[]){
    memmove(array, array+1, (size-1) * sizeof(array[0]));
    array[size-1] = 0;
}
```